# jquery.timeago plugin not showing elapsed time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been trying to add jquery.timeago plugin to my project to show the time that has elapsed since a date (e.g. `3 weeks ago`). I can't seem to get it working completely. I am working on a .NET core website if that's relevant.

This is how I add the jquery.timeago plugin to my page:

```
@section javascript{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("time.timeago").timeago();
        });
    </script>
}
```

The element I added to the page:

```
<abbr class="timeago" datetime="@fileNode.CommitData.CommittedDate" title="@fileNode.CommitData.CommittedDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)"></abbr>
```

Which turns into the following when rendered:

```
<abbr class="timeago" datetime="31-5-2017 15:17:21" title="31 mei 2017, 15:17:21"></abbr>
```

However this still doesn't show me the time that has actually elapsed (so `1 day ago` for this example). When I add some text between the opening and closing tags i.e. `<abbr ...>abc</abbr>` I see this on my page, so I know the timeago plugin is loaded correctly:
[image: timeago plugin loading]

Any suggestions as to why it doesn't show the elapsed time? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe I missed this, but I was invoking `timeago()` on all `time` elements. Which I didn't have, I was using `abbr` element.

So to fix, I just had to change:

```
$("time.timeago").timeago();
```

into

```
$("abbr.timeago").timeago();
```